# Icon and menu items getting disabled on Scribble for iPad

Tags: ipad, notes.app, ipados

While using Scribble on an iPad, the carriage return icon is disabled, and the Show Keyboard menu item is too. This occurred while using the Apple Notes app.

Why do they become disabled? How do I get them back?

Comment: To be more precise, did the CR icon and the Show Keyboard menu item become disabled _after_ you invoked the Apple Notes app?

Comment: @IconDaemon Sometimes in Notes app I can use the carriage return button and keyboard menu, sometimes I cannot. I have not yet detected the pattern to their becoming enabled or disabled at seemingly random times. Hence my Question here.

Comment: Ahhh.. Scribble is a native iOS function as of iOS 14. I was not aware of this because I don't use an Apple Pencil with my older iPad. If you quit and reopen the Notes app, and don't use Scribble to enter text, do the missing options stay enabled/visible? Do you use Scribble in other iOS apps?